# How to publish a post to all my app users?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post to all my app user wall 
& and i use this code to post to only one user : ==>>

this code to post in only one wall

```
 <?

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                      'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                                 ));
        echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                       )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
      // Give the user a logout link 
      echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
    } else {

      // No user, so print a link for the user to login
      // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_stream permission
      // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
      // need to specify it here.
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    } 

  ?>      

  </body> 
</html>
```

How to publish a post to all my app users ?!!

please advice !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all the app users-

   With FQL, just do :

   ```
   $fql="SELECT uid FROM user
   WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = ".$me['id'].")
   AND is_app_user = 1";
   ```
2. Loop through each user and use **feed**